# How to convert [element, element, element] into [(1, element), (2, element), (3, element)]

Tags: python

Say I have a list:
my_list = ['foo', 'fa', 'goo']

I would like to turn this list into this:
[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'fa'), (3, 'goo')]

This way, I could iterate over the list and see what number it is in the list. Any help would be appreciated, I have been wondering what function does this for so long, I just don't know what exactly to search to find the answer.
[image]

Comment: The function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) does exactly this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function `enumerate(iterable)` is made to do literally this:

```
new_list = list(enumerate(my_list))
# [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'fa'), (2, 'goo')]
```

Giving a second argument to `enumerate()` will let you choose what index to start at, so you can 1-index:

```
new_list = list(enumerate(my_list, 1))
# [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'fa'), (3, 'goo')]
```

You can alternatively use a list comprehension to 1-index it, if you need to:

```
new_list = [(i+1, v) for (i, v) in enumerate(my_list)]
# [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'fa'), (3, 'goo')]
```

Comment: `enumerate()` takes a second positional argument which specifies the starting value: `enumerate(my_list, 1)` would start the numbering at 1. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: @Diggy. I didn't actually know that was a thing! Thanks for the heads-up, I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I haven't scripted in python for so long so I forgot that enumerate was used to get the number of the element when iterating over it.

Comment: I recommend using a keyword argument `enumerate(..., start=1)` so the code is more readable.